# How to ask for gps permission using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gps

How to request GPS permission when the user **Blocks** the GPS permission!

Means how to again show user the **Allow** or **Block** box, so that user could choose it again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can or should do that anyways if the user has blocked location-services. If some features of your application is not working properly without location permission you could show an info-box to the user, and kindly ask them to turn it on.